# Best practice to locally register Vue components in Blade template (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm building a MPA project with Laravel + Vue where I currently register all components globally, so my **app.js** looks like this:

```
Vue.component(...)
Vue.component(...)
...
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

I am thinking it might be better if we register just some global components and then register local components for a specific blade view.

Let's say in the **js/components** folder I have a **global** folder contains all global components and a **auth/login** folder contains all components for the login page.

And for the login blade view:

```
@extends(layouts.app)
@section('content')
   <div id="login-page">
   </div>
@endsection
```

What would be the best practice to structure files/register Vue components  for this specific blade view?

Pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I arrange my components on a functionality basis. One folder per functionality in js/components (and sub-folders if the view is complex). Then I have a components-loader.js file where I keep track of all my global components. The components-loader.js only contains the root components and the partials imported in vue, basically creating a chain.

In the components-loader.js file I load the components in a way that Webpack can use chunking, so each component have it's own chunk-x.js file. And simply require the loader in your app.js, this way the app.js can be a lot smaller.

```
components-loader.js:
Vue.component('example-component', function (resolve) {
  require(['./exampleFunctionality/exampleComponent'], resolve);
});

app.js:
require("./components/components-loader");
```

Create the folder /public/chunks and in webpack.mix.js put at the end:

```
.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        chunkFilename: `chunks/[name]${mix.config.inProduction ? '[chunkhash].chunk.js' : '.chunk.js'}`,
        publicPath: '/',
    },
});
```

Now if you run npm run dev/prod one folder of components will be one chunk, and webpack only pulls the files to the browser when it's used. It has a small delay, but worth it in my opinion.

Then in your blade view just use the root component.

```
@extends(layouts.app)
@section('content')
   <example-component :prop1="asdasd" :prop2="basdasd"></example-component>
@endsection
```

This might not be the best way but it works nicely for me.